# Linux, How to using cut command with delimiters double quote?

Tags: linux, cut

i have a a line of text file contain this :

```
$gVER = "4.027.160921.1";
```

how to using cut in linux to delete `double quotes` and also the last (;), i just want to put the numbers value only. what i already try is this :

```
exec( "cat /web/FunctionInit.inc.php | grep gVER | cut -d \"=\" -f2"
```

when i using this code the result is :

```
"4.027.160921.1";
```

how to delimiters `double quotes` and the last (;) using cut linux?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This could work for you

```
 echo '"4.027.160921.1";' | cut -d'"' -f 2
```

Comment: `cut -d \"` is a better delimiter for quotes if you use it in a shell `alias`